# Expanding Training Data for Intent and Entity Recognition Model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have a specific use case where I need to identify both intent and entities within a given statement. For example, given the statement "Book train tickets from Mumbai to Delhi," the intent is "BOOK_TRAIN_TICKETS," and the entities are "source = Mumbai" and "destination = Delhi."

Currently, my model is experiencing overfitting due to limited training data. To address this issue, I've attempted to use data augmenters such as **nlpaug** with contextual word embedding augmentations. However, the results aren't as accurate as I'd like.

I'm seeking advice on any tools or libraries that can help generate additional training data with similar contextual relevance. For instance, I'd like to generate statements like "Mumbai to Delhi train tickets" to diversify the training data.

Any guidance or recommendations on tools, libraries, or techniques for this data augmentation process would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!